# Example of amortized analysis of algorithms rather than data structures

Tags: algorithms

[Amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) is often taught in algorithms classes, with the different *methods* (aggregate, accounting, potential). It is *very important* when discussing some data structures and their use in algorithms since worst-case analysis is sometimes quite far from the actual behavior.

My question is: Where is an amortized analysis used, **not** related to data structures?

Two points to clarify what I mean by *not related to data structures*:

1. Amortized analysis can be used to analyze [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm), but it is very much related to data structure: the amortized aspect is related to the *union-find* data structure.
2. The [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the gcd of two integers $a$ and $b$ can be analyzed through amortized analysis: though some step decreases $b$ only by one unit, it actually decreases by a constant factor *in average*. *Cf.* for instance [this paper](http://www.lirmm.fr/%7Egrenet/publis/GV20.pdf) (*caveat: I am one of the authors*) that uses a potential function or the analysis in Knuth's book. I consider that this is amortized analysis not related to the data structure.

Of course, the border between *related to data structure* and *not related to data structure* is probably ill-defined. A more precise version of my question could then be: What are examples of amortized analysis of algorithms, that are least related to data structure?

Comment: Another classical example is "Can I optimize an operation that I will have to repeat `m` times on my collection of items, by first moving my `n` items into a well-suited data structure?" And then you need to compare the cost of building a data structure (which depends on n and will be higher for a complex structure) with the repeated cost of the operation (which is of the form `m * something(n)` where the something might be lower for a complex structure).

Answer (score 1):

Amortized analysis is appropriate to analyse a *sequence* of operations. That is where your "data structure" bent comes into the picture. Your example of the analysis of the Euclidean algorithm is a case in point: You analyse the behaviour of a sequence of non-trivial operations on a very simple data structure (two elements).

In any case, Jeff Erickson (of [Algorithms](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms) fame) said he hasn't used his amortized analysis notes for quite some time.